# Blue image for buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have buttons in my costoum cell , and i'm setting the images from code . But something strange is happening. My images are blue .

```
 BOOL isTheObjectThere = [self.favoriteArry containsObject:self.tableData[indexPath.row]];
        if (isTheObjectThere==TRUE) {
            cell.favBtn.hidden = NO;
            [cell.favBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite_star.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            cell.favBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
            [cell.favBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(unfavoriteBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

[image]

Comment: It should no be this      `[cell.favBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"history@3x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];` You have to use this  `[cell.favBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"history.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: the result is the same

Comment: Try changing button type from default to custom.

Comment: I don't know whether the system will use a proper scale version if you init the image this way and to be honest don't want to test it, but it's worth to visually check first all image versions (normal, @2x, @3x). A screenshot would be nice too.

Comment: i added an image . I don't have blue stars in my project. All are green.

Comment: Perhaps try `theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];` or `theButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should create the button with a UIButtonTypeCustom type in case it's currently set to UIButtonTypeSystem and you want to avoid the tint color from taking over. Alternatively, you can set the image rendering mode to make sure you always get the original image and not a tinted one:

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite_star.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
```